# Who gets listed on a close as duplicate message?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just flagged a question as a duplicate. A few minutes later the question was closed as a duplicate with only a much higher rep user's name and Community (two users total) in the close message.

Why doesn't my name appear in the close message since I was the first to flag it?